# Yelp V2 API using SignPost from Java - INVALID_SIGNATURE

Tags: java, web-services, oauth, signpost

Trying to call the v2 api from a Java app (Android), utilizing the 
SignPost oauth library.  I have extracted my code into a standalone 
version that can be run from the command line (no dependencies on 
Android).  Please have a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

You can run the example directly by typing:  java -jar YelpV2Test.jar 
Also I have included a zip file which is the source code, and required 
libraries, setup as an Eclipse project.  Also am pasting the code 
directly below.

[Both the Executable-JAR and source ZIP file can be downloaded from my 
Google Docs share](https://docs.google.com/#folders/0BxrV1XS12N53OTJkMTIwYjctOWE5NC00NjU0LThkMjktMGUyNTdkY2ViMTFl).

I tried changing over from GET to POST, and got the exact same 
result.  No problems using the v1 API.    Any help on resolving this 
would be appreciated!

-- Start of Code --

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException; 
import java.net.MalformedURLException; 
import java.net.URLEncoder; 


import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer; 
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer; 
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException; 
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException; 
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException; 
import oauth.signpost.signature.HmacSha1MessageSigner; 
import oauth.signpost.signature.QueryStringSigningStrategy; 


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity; 
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse; 
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; 
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet; 
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; 
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils; 


public class RunMe { 
        public final String CONSUMER_KEY = "PbSjw9p08To_HZnFYqpRZg"; 
        public final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "_raqYwj6njZ15sXj4z-CYEDHiHQ"; 
        public final String TOKEN = "ARfbDucxkBi89lBHARTgygLkcMw9h8eW"; 
        public final String TOKEN_SECRET = "rzvmIKVC4WQsdZV1lM5naZ5IQ8g"; 
        public final String YWSID = "iXUUomsyqBkdXaypz7539A"; 
        public final String ENCODING_SCHEME = "UTF-8"; 

        public void start() { 
                String lat = "30.361471"; 
                String lng = "-87.164326"; 
                String category = "banks"; 
                String radius = "10"; 
                String limit = "15"; 
                String offset = "0"; 
                String sort = "0"; 
                String service = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search"; 

                try { 
                        String query = String 
                                        .format(service 
                                                        + "?ll=%s&category_filter=%s&radius_filter=%s&limit=%s&offset= 
%s&sort=%s", 
                                                        URLEncoder.encode(lat + "," + lng, ENCODING_SCHEME), 
                                                        URLEncoder.encode(category, ENCODING_SCHEME), 
                                                        URLEncoder.encode(radius, ENCODING_SCHEME), 
                                                        URLEncoder.encode(limit, ENCODING_SCHEME), 
                                                        URLEncoder.encode(offset, ENCODING_SCHEME), 
                                                        URLEncoder.encode(sort, ENCODING_SCHEME)); 
                        OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, 
                                        CONSUMER_SECRET); 
                        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET); 
                        consumer.setMessageSigner(new HmacSha1MessageSigner()); 
                        consumer.setSendEmptyTokens(true); 
                        consumer.setSigningStrategy(new QueryStringSigningStrategy()); 
                        String signedQuery = consumer.sign(query); 
                        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ">> " + "Signed query: " 
                                        + signedQuery); 
                        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(signedQuery); 
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(request); 

                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
                        String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
                        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ">> " + "Result: " 
                                        + result);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                } catch (IOException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
        }

        /** 
         * @param args 
         */ 
        public static void main(String[] args) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                new RunMe().start(); 
        }
}
```

-- End of Code --

The results I'm seeing printed from this test are as follows:

$ java -jar YelpV2Test.jar

RunMe>> Signed query: 
http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?ll=30.361471%2C-87.164326&category_filter=banks&radius_filter=10&limit=15&offset=0&sort=0&oauth_signature=cf5C3%2BjIfTvNIQee1buzWk2%2Fz%2BE%3D&oauth_token=ARfbDucxkBi89lBHARTgygLkcMw9h8eW&oauth_consumer_key=PbSjw9p08To_HZnFYqpRZg&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1296021631&oauth_nonce=4831286657125973388

RunMe>> Result: {"error":{"text":"Signature was 
invalid","id":"INVALID_SIGNATURE","description":"Invalid signature. 
Expected signature base string: GET&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.yelp.com 
%2Fv2%2Fsearch&category_filter%3Dbanks%26limit%3D15%26ll 
%3D30.361471%252C-87.164326%26oauth_consumer_key 
%3DPbSjw9p08To_HZnFYqpRZg%26oauth_nonce 
%3D4831286657125973388%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC- 
SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1296021631%26oauth_token 
%3DARfbDucxkBi89lBHARTgygLkcMw9h8eW%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26offset 
%3D0%26radius_filter%3D10%26sort%3D0"}}

Comment: did u find any solution????????

Comment: I ended up using another library.  There were some bugs using SignPost with Android.  It may be fixed by now I'm not sure.

Comment: what library did u use?

Comment: I used scribe oauth java lib.  See: http://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java